# PSR for nested IF condition

Tags: php, psr-2, psr-1

I am just to migrate my code in to PSR standard. I am not sure about how to write it inside nested condition. I am confused by line spacing. Can I use one line space after If condition ? Below is my example code.

```
if ($this->value) {
    if ($this->value === 'abc') {
         $x = $this->x();
    }

    $x = 'lababala';

    if ($this->value === '123') {
         $x = $this->y();
    }

    $end = new object();
}
```

Comment: This looks good to me. Its the same as I do at work.

Comment: I was bit confused so asked it and there is not clarification for nested loop on PSR site. why marked it down ? Cheers!

Comment: I didnt marked it down as I don't think this is a bad question.

Comment: Oops Sorry for that :)